# Why the line is printed twice?

Tags: c, unix, fork, zombie-process

I am new to UNIX programming and i was reading about zombie processes and how to avoid them using fork() twice. I read the code from a book and tried to run it on my system.. I am using ubuntu 12.04. I ran the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>   
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    if(pid = fork() < 0)
        printf("Fork Error.!!!\n");
    else 
    if(pid == 0)
    {
        if((pid = fork()) < 0)
             printf("Fork2 Error.!!!\n");
        else 
             if(pid > 0)
                   exit(0);

        sleep(2);
        printf("Second Child, parent id: %d\n", getppid());
        exit(0);
    }
    if(waitpid(pid, NULL, 0) != pid)
        printf("Waitpid Error.!!!\n");

    exit(0);
}
```

The output that i get is as follows:

```
Second Child, parent id: 1
Second Child, parent id: 1
```

The book says this should be printed only once and that is also what i feel should happen when i see what's happening in the code. I dont understand why its getting printed twice. I found this code at many places on the net but could not get something that explains this. Any help is welcome. Thanks.!!

Comment: try adding fflush(0) after each printf

Comment: tip: fix your indentation. that code is very hard to follow because your randomish-arbitrary positioning.

Comment: @Gir: still it prints twice.!!

Comment: Are you sure this is the code -- no extra `{` or `}`?

Comment: yeah. kinda sure. crosschecked it.

Comment: and `if(pid == 0)` is not `if(pid = 0)`?

Comment: @Hogan, Yes it is not so. It will give a waitpid error. And that is also printed twice.

Comment: If you are using gcc, you should add `-Wall` to all your compilation commands. It would have told you about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

second line of the code in main - missing brackets around `pid = fork()`

```
if( ( pid = fork() ) < 0){
```

Comment: You are right :D -- pid was assigned the result of the compare.

Comment: Woah.!! That's the case. Small little things that matter.!! This helps me print the line only once. Thanks.!!

Answer (score 5):

In this line:

```
if(pid = fork() < 0)
```

you should add parentheses around the `pid = fork()` part, like you did for the other fork. You are assigning the result of `fork() < 0` to `pid`. As long as the fork didn't fail, that means `pid` is becoming 0 in both the parent and the child of the first fork, so you're getting 2 processes running the child branch (each one creating a child of its own) and none running the `waitpid`.

Comment: Thanks mate.!! That's the thing. Wish i could mark two answers as correct but i chose the one that came first.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this [link](http://www.steve.org.uk/Reference/Unix/faq_2.html#SEC6). It says:

> There are a few differences between exit() and _exit() that become
>   significant when fork(), and especially vfork(), is used.
>
> ...
>
> In the child branch of a fork(), it is normally incorrect to use exit(),
>   because that can lead to stdio buffers being flushed twice, and
>   temporary files being unexpectedly removed.

This makes sense to me, and you need to update the code accordingly to get the results as expected.

Answer (score -1):

In

```
pid_t pid;
if(pid = fork() < 0)
printf("Fork Error.!!!\n");
```

a thread will be created. So currently we have two threads main thread and child thread. In line

```
if(pid == 0)
```

you are checking the current thread in child thread. Again you created a new thread in line

```
if((pid = fork()) < 0)
     printf("Fork2 Error.!!!\n");
else if(pid > 0)        //Do nothing if this is parent thread.
     exit(0);
```

So now you have tho threads running and it will execute

```
printf("Second Child, parent id: %d\n", getppid());
```

So you are getting the message printed twice.

Comment: `if(pid > 0) exit(0);` should cause the parent to exit without printing the line.